# User View List in Drupal filter by taxonomy

Tags: users, views

In a social website powered by Drupal, Users are allowed to add interest tags into a taxonomy terms by autotagging.

My problem is how to create a view page to list all users based on a certain interest in the term list.

Say, I need to display user interested on PHP.

Comment: Is your tagging done on your profile by a term relationship field ?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using the [views module](http://drupal.org/project/views). Its the Drupal GUI way to build queries so you will be able to crate a page that lists all users based on the field you need.

Here goes a really good reference that may help you with that:

http://nodeone.se/en/taming-the-beast-learn-views-with-nodeone

If you prefer to get your hands dirty you can use the [Entity Field Query](http://drupal.org/node/1343708)

Comment: Here goes a question about views tutorials that may be helpful too: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/673/where-is-a-detailed-tutorial-on-views